# Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError on Next.js 13 with sentry

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, sentry, next.js13

I created Next.js 13 project with sentry(automated installation) and i did nothing on files but when it tries to compile file C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Work\project\sentry.server.config.ts it seems like it skips character \ in path

Here is a full error:

```
- error C:UsersmyuserDesktopWork
projectsentry.server.config.ts
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "C:UsersmyuserDesktopWork
projectsentry.server.config.ts" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "c:" URIs.
Import trace for requested module:
C:UsersmyuserDesktopWork
projectsentry.server.config.ts
./app/page.tsx
```

I tried:
I searched github issues and stackoverflow and googling and GPT(Bard, Bing Chat) and non of these worked.

Comment: Can you share the place that references this file?

Comment: @Mureinik  webpack on C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Work\project\ but i don't know exact path

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I've been hitting the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maintainer of the Sentry Next.js SDK here. This should be fixed with version 7.53.0 of the SDK. [Relevant changelog entry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/releases/tag/7.53.0#:%7E:text=Import%20path%20issue%20on%20Windows)